# How to resize the height of title bar in Windows API?

Tags: c, winapi, tdm-gcc

I wanna increase height of titlebar of my app which written in c language using TDM_GCC libraries.
I didn't mean change the height of titlebar of all apps in windows. Only my app.
What I want like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is: *How do I adjust the sizing of the non-client area of a Win32 window?*

This is probably what you want:

[Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe)

[image]